# How to install m68k cross compilation toolchain on sid?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

My end goal is to be able to compile and run m68k programs using my amd64 VM. I have had luck doing this for ppc64el, mips64el, sparc64, and so on. It's just this weird thing with apt that happens specifically for the g++-m68k-linux-gnu package.

## Source

https://github.com/mcandre/mucus/blob/issue-8/m68k/bootstrap.sh#L9-L13

## Trace

```
default: Fetched 20.1 MB in 4s (5,374 kB/s)
default: Reading package lists...
default: Reading package lists...
default: Building dependency tree...
default: Reading state information...
default: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
default: requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
default: distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
default: or been moved out of Incoming.
default: The following information may help to resolve the situation:
default: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
default:  g++-m68k-linux-gnu : Depends: cpp-m68k-linux-gnu (= 4:8.3.0-2.1) but it is not going to be installed
default:                       Depends: gcc-m68k-linux-gnu (= 4:8.3.0-2.1) but it is not going to be installed
default:                       Depends: g++-8-m68k-linux-gnu (>= 8.3.0-1~) but it is not going to be installed
default: E
default: : 
default: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any tips for resolving this dependency conflict?

Comment: I suspect this might be as simple as: There is no *precompiled* m68k gcc (i.e. **g++-m68k-linux-gnu**) available in the repositories. Solution: Compile it locally(!?)